# Cowardly - Adjective or Adverb?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech, adverb-placement, adjective-order

*In the following sentence, is the word **'cowardly'** an **adjective** or **adverb**?*

> He acted in a cowardly manner.

What I understand is the word **cowardly** is modifying the verb **act**. So it should be an **adverb**. But in the phrase **a cowardly manner**, the word is used in an **adjective** or **pre-modifier** place.
***Am I missing something?***

Comment: I'd say it's an adjective modifying the noun "manner". Just because it has an -_ly_ suffix doesn't mean it's an adverb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He acted in a cowardly manner.

"Cowardly" here is an adjective.

We usually have the structure `a + adj + noun`, which is the case here.

The base noun of ["cowardly"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cowardly) is ["coward"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coward), which means "a person who's not brave and is too eager to avoid danger".